# How to correctly retrieve int from a Google App Engine datastore (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a servlet that needs to retrieve an `Entity` from a GAE datastore, and then perform certain tasks depending on the entity's "STAGE" property, which is an integer. My code ends up looking like this:

```
switch( (int) (long) (Long) phrase.getProperty("STAGE")){
```

This works fine but the code is incredibly ugly and I can't help thinking this can be accomplished in a simpler and perhaps more efficient way.

Thank you,
Billy

Comment: Its java, nothing is as simple as it should be.

Comment: If `STAGE` was saved as long then you should treat is as long.

Comment: ((Long) phrase.getProperty("STAGE")).intValue() if you are sure that there will be always not null value.

Answer (score 0):

switch( ((Number)phrase.getProperty("STAGE")).intValue() ) {